# Как сохранить изображения из строки JSON на сервер php

Tags: php, json

Нужно сохранять в отдельную папку на сервак с названием ID, сам не могу представить как это можно сделать.

```
{
"data":[
           {
               "Id":"56021070",
               "images":"http://test.ru/2182788746.jpg, http://test.ru/2182789008.jpg"  
           }
       ] 
}
```

Comment: Начнем с того что у вас джсон невалидный

Comment: спасибо исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr=json_decode($json); //Переводим json в массив 
foreach ($arr as $elem){
    if (!file_exists("/path/to/my/dir".$elem['Id'])){
        mkdir("/path/to/my/dir".$elem['Id']); //Создаём папку если её не существует
    }
    $imageArr=explode(',' $elem['images']) //Получаем массив ссылок
    foreach ($imageArr as $image){
        $imageNameList=explode('/',$image);
        $imageName=$imageNameList[count($imageNameList)-1] //Можно лучше сгенерировать имя. Это для примера.
        copy ($image,"/path/to/my/dir".$elem['Id']."/".$imageName); //Копируем изображение
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо взял ваш вариант настроил со своими нуждами, но другой вопрос одну картинку сохраняет а как быть со второй.

Comment: Все спасибо разобрался !!

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант

```
$path = '/my/folder';
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$urls = explode(',',$data['data']['images']);
foreach($urls as $url){
    $url   = trim($url);
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $name  = $path.$parts['path'];
    file_put_contents($name, file_get_contents($url));
}
```

Второй вариант

строку `file_put_contents($name, file_get_contents($url));` меняем на

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
$fp = fopen($name, 'wb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```